# Next code runs in FireFox and Chrome. What's the error when when I run it in IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to get an element bouncing box, as this:

```
var bboxRealDibujo = gRootDibujo.getBoundingClientRect();           //El bbox del dibujo.
    var bboxRealVentanaDeZoom = ventanaDeZoom.getBoundingClientRect();  //El bbox de la ventana de zoom.

    console.log ("Lienzo XY: "+bboxRealDibujo.left+", "+bboxRealDibujo.top+"     /     Lienzo WH "+ bboxRealDibujo.width+", "+bboxRealDibujo.height);
    console.log ("Ventana Zoom XY:"+bboxRealVentanaDeZoom.left+", "+bboxRealVentanaDeZoom.top+"     /     Lienzo WH"+ bboxRealVentanaDeZoom.width+", "+bboxRealVentanaDeZoom.height);
```

As you can see in the attached image, I haven't any problem in Firefox / chrome, but in IE, The variables x,y returns as "undefined" (also tried with left, top, same result).

The question is: is a type command error, or IE has it's own commands (as usual)?

Thanks in advance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed4Eu.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect), IE supports `getBoundingClientRect`, but it doesn't support the `x` and `y` properties.

> IE and Edge return a (ClientRectList with) MSDN: ClientRect objects which do not contain x and y properties, instead of DOMRect objects

An alternative would be to use `rect.left` and `rect.top` instead of `x` and `y` respectively.